# ActiveAdmin collection action path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

How do I set the url for a "semantic form" tag in an activeAdmin custom page partial for collection_action in my activeAdmin controller?

I have:

item.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Item, :as => "MyItems" do
  menu :parent => "My", :label => "My Items"

  collection_action :add_me, :method => :post do
    redirect_to "/" # just for testing
  end
end
```

custom page ActiveAdmin controller

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "MyItemsCustomPage" do
  content do
    @items = Item.all
    render "item", { :items => @items }
  end
end
```

_item.html.erb (for custom page)

```
<%= semantic_form_for :item_add_me, :url => add_me_admin_items_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.buttons :commit %>
<% end %>
```

And after going to the custom page I have the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `add_me_admin_items_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000006c3ff40>:0x00000005f8bd80>
```

btw, semantic form for `admin_items_path` works well for item add action.

PS. If I change the url to `/admin/items/add_me` and set the `:method` to `:post`, I get the routing error: `No route matches [POST] "/admin/items/add_me"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

After removing `:as => "MyItems"` in item.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Item do
```

All works ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `ActiveAdmin.register Item, as: "MyItems"` actually renames all your routes to be `my_items` instead of `my_item` in all the method names. So, in your form, instead of using `add_me_admin_items_path`, you could have used `add_me_admin_my_items_path`.